# How to change header height in react-navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tried different things none of them working, documentation also doesn't help

```
<MainFlowStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'left', shadowColor: 'transparent', headerStyle: {height: 200}}}
    >
      <MainFlowStack.Screen name="RoutinesList" component={RoutinesListScreen} option={{headerStyle: {height: 600}}} options={{
        headerTitle: (props) =>
          (<View style={{width: '100%'}}>
            <Text style={styles.header1}>
              Your Workouts
            </Text>
          </View>),
        headerShadowVisible: false,
        headerStyle: {height: 100}
      }} />
      <MainFlowStack.Screen name="RoutineScreen" component={RoutineScreen} options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.name })} />
    </MainFlowStack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `headerStyle` prop for the `Stack.Navigator` does not support setting a custom height. From the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerstyle):

> **headerStyle​**
>
> Style object for header. Supported properties:
>
> - backgroundColor

As far as I am concerned, this has changed compared to react-navigation `v5`.

However, we could provide a custom header component and set a specific height this way.

```js
<Stack.Screen
  options={
    header: (props) =>
        (
          <View style={{ height: 100 }}>
            ... 
          </View>
        ),
  }
/>
```

Comment: Solve a problem, react-navigation@6.4.2. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that:

```
<Stack.Screen screenOptions={{ headerStyle: { height: 50} }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, but @fabriziocucci i actually right. You can edit height of header.

I created custom component for header and just passed it in header prop like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
      header: NavHeader,
      })}>
    <Tab.Screen name="myComponent" component={myComponent}/>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

and then in styles:

```
style={{width: '100%', maxHeight: 20}}
```

Comment: But @fabriziocucci said it is possible to change the height from headerStyle, and not defining a whole custom header and set height to it

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set height of header from Tabs Stack options and not from the normal Stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

David's answer is not entirely correct. Even though the V6 doc doesn't mention it, I just tested that you can actually set the header height as follows:

```
<Stack.Screen
  component={MyScreen}
  name="TripScreen"
  options={() => ({
    headerStyle: { height: 96 }
  })}
/>
```

Comment: note that this is only works with JS stack navigator

Answer (score -4):

Here, I change the height of header using ... headerStyle height. And believe me, works!

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="Preferences"
  component={ProfilePreferences}
  options={{
    headerTitle: () => <Header name="Preferences" />,
    headerStyle: {
      height: 102,
      backgroundColor: colors.dark,
      elevation: 0
    },
  }}
/>
```